# Recurrent actions via OpenShift

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift

I have an application (Spring Boot + Hibernate + Postgres) which executes ETL process. The application is deployed in OpenShift and has a scale n > 1, so this application always has more than 1 replica. But if every app launched own ETL in same database then data wouldn't be consistent.
Therefore, I think the process should be launched via something external. 
I see a decision of my task as a method of API which can "doEtl()" and the method can be called a kubernete (OS) 'schedule' or another kuber (OS) tool. However I can't understand how to google it. I try to look for 'kubernetes custom schedule' but the found results explain 'how to work' or how to write custom the schedule for auto-scale.

Can someone advice me, if it is generally possible and if yes how to google it or how to named it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for the `CronJobs` object that is available and can be used to regularly execute a certain action.

For OpenShift, you can find more information in the documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/nodes/jobs/nodes-nodes-jobs.html